# XML Serialize - BIG Data ( 20GB ), OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, out-of-memory

I have a problem: I want to serialize an xml ( 20GB ) but I get an `out of memory` exception.

Do you have any suggestion for this ?

The code I had is below:

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    string retval = string.Empty;

    if (null!= obj)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
        {                    
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            // We are ommitting the namespace to simplifying passing as parameter
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");

            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }

        retval = sb.ToString();
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Flush, batch writing.

Comment: @Karolis Thx for fast responding, can you give me an example or how can I do it ? I don t know exactly how to use it

Comment: sorry, can't expand on topic right now. If needed will elaborate later today.

Comment: I believe you have a very huge collection of some items. In this case you can iterate over them writing elements manually. Then you won't need whole 20gb for the operation.

Comment: I wonder if your computer can handle such huge file unless you have huge memory.  As you are returning xml serialized object as string memory requirement for that can be more than 20 GB. 

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/120840/Xml-Serialization-on-large-xml-files 

this can be a valuable resource.

Comment: `public static string Serialize(object obj)` - who will call this method and what will happen with the String returned? Will it be saved to file? Returned to client of a webservice? Saved to database?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl with the string returned I will generate an xls file on another thread.

Comment: ...so, in the end, you want to generate >20GB XLS file?

Comment: @AdrianAldea why not just create the xls file from the original object model? what does xml add to this mix?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl xls file size is smaller than xml size.

Comment: alright, sorry, let me restate the question: are you going to dump all the data from OBJ (or XML) into the Excel file verbatim? or, maybe, is the `other thread` reading the XML data, calculating some statistics, and writing only the statistics to that XLS file without the full input data?

Comment: @MarcGravell I can't to that because I had a dispatcher that using some execute commands with string return. The data is serialized to string and that string is sent in chunks to UI, after this another tread will convert string to xml then to xls :) Is wierd but I can't modify the design of the app

Comment: Is there another solution to this as a 20GB XML file seems way too large. The way it's being created should be changed to reduce the size. What is the structure like? Could it be split into smaller files?
The other option would be to fire up a Super computer with lots of memory on the cloud for a day and process your file once and hope to not have to do it again.

Comment: @AdrianAldea you need a new design *anyway*; you **can't have** a 20GB `string` object in .NET

Comment: your workaround is wrong. Instead of collecting the incoming bits into a huge pile (or at least this is how I understood what you said - sorry if I got it wrong), save and serialize it in chunks as they come in, and immediatelly drop them out of the memory - they are already saved, so you dont need to hog them in memory. The "other thread" will be then not only able to read the chunks from files, but also **will be able to detect** that new file arrived, and see what new data arrived instead of reading whole pile of poo again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20 GB is *never* going to work as a `string` (via `StringBuilder`); even with `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` enabled, the maxiumum theoretical length of a `string` is a tiny fraction of that.

If you want huge data, you need to use something like a file (or basically: a `Stream` that isn't `MemoryStream`) as the backend.

I would also say that xml is a terrible choice for large data. If you aren't tightly bound to xml, I would strongly recommend looking at alternative tools (I'm happy to offer advice, if that is an option).

But for now:

```
string path = "my.xml";
XmlWriterSettings settings = ...
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings))
{
    // ...
}
```

or if you're actually talking to a socket etc:

```
Stream stream = ...
XmlWriterSettings settings = ...
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I created a local .xml file, now i have problem with a OLEDB error "System resourse exceeded" but I will find a fix

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a List to do it in pieces

```
        public static void Serialize(List<MyClass> myClasses)
        {
            string retval = string.Empty;

            if (myClasses != null)
            {

                using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter("filename", false))
                {
                    foreach (MyClass myClass in myClasses)
                    {

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        using (XmlWriter writer1 = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
                        {
                            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(myClass.GetType());

                            // We are ommitting the namespace to simplifying passing as parameter
                            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                            ns.Add("", "");

                            serializer.Serialize(writer1, myClass);
                        }
                        sWriter.Write(sb.ToString());

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: that code will create an xml file with multiple root elements

Comment: Yes.  But you can modify to write an opening and closing tag.